# ffmpeg over https fails

Tags: https, ffmpeg

If I feed `url` with `http`, such as this:

```
ffmpeg -i http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4 videojs.mp4
```

It works perfectly. However, when I feed `url` with `https`, such as this:

```
ffmpeg -i https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/check.mp4 video.mp4
```

This gives me an error:

> https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls, or
>   securetransport enabled.
>   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/check.mp4: Protocol not
>   found

What should I do to enable https?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer can be found in the error message.

> Recompile FFmpeg with openssl, ...

So, recompile `ffmpeg` with the required dependencies.
You can read more about the process [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), and during the `./configure` step, just add `--enable-openssl`.

Make sure that you have these packages installed: `build-essential`, `openssl`, `libssl-dev`

In the comments, you said that you're using Ubuntu, so you can easily install these packages using `apt-get install`.

After installation, you can execute `ffmpeg -protocols` to make sure that you have `https` listed there.

By the way, your video (on `AWS`), can be accessed via the `http` protocol.

Comment: Yes, How do I install it? I am using ubuntu inside a virtualbox and not very good at it. Will you please kindly show me how?

Comment: Install openssl-dev also, and then recompile ffmpeg so it detects openssl during configure, and is compiled with ssl support. Your installed version was not compiled with ssl support.

Comment: Yes, after recompiling `ffmpeg`, you can execute `ffmpeg -protocols` and make sure that `https` is listed there.

Comment: In order to install `openssl-dev`, execute: `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: I am sorry if this is a noob question, but how to recompile ffmpeg? I have installed libssl-dev.

Comment: @unixarmy `./configure --with-openssl` this gives me an error: `Unknown option "--with-openssl".`

Comment: What about ``--enable-openssl``?

Comment: I tried `--enable-openssl` (in the prompt it is listed in the `Enabled protocols list`) and after that `make` and `make install`. But there's still not `https` protocol in `ffmpeg protocols` only `http`. Am I missing somethig?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83782/discussion-between-unixarmy-and-robin).

Comment: This answer should be edited to reflect the renamed flag (see other answers).

Comment: `--with-openssl` was never an option for FFmpeg. That's a Homebrew option.

Comment: Just sharing that on CentOS I was having issues installing "libssl-dev" . I googled and found that I should install openssl-devel instead. "sudo yum install openssl-devel" worked for me.

Comment: Alternative options are `--enable-gnutls`, `--enable-libtls` and `--enable-mbedtls`, see `./configure --help`

Answer (score 16):

The correct answer to this question as of Sep 2015 is
`./configure --enable-openssl` and if you have ubuntu then make sure you `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`.

Comment: any idea how to do this for openwrt?

Comment: @owengerig `opkg install openssl-util`? Maybe it's `libopenssl`?

Comment: both of those are installed, but https is not listed as protocol and error is same.  id thought i need to change a config or rebuild with opensll

Answer (score 10):

Add  `--enable-openssl to the ./configure line`.

The `--with-openssl` does not work presently.

This is my whole line:

```
$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME/scr1/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-   
I$HOME/scr1/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-
L$HOME/scr1/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/scr1/bin" --pkg-config-
flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-
libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-openssl
```

Comment: Mote compilation help: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide